# Dibujar tabla dinamica en php

Tags: php, tcpdf

Tengo el siguiente array

```
$arreglo=[1,2,3,4,5..50]
```

Quiero mostrarlos en una tabla, pero que la tabla sea de 10 columnas tipo asi:

```
1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
etc...
```

El numero de filas depende del tamaño del arreglo divido por 10, redondeado al mayor, por ejemplo, si tengo 25 datos en el arreglo (por ende 25 posiciones) entonces el numero de filas serian 3, tengo este codigo, pero me muestra solo las 10 primeras posiciones y no el resto

```
for($j = 0; $j < $rows;){
     $html2.='<tr>';
     for($k = 0;$k < 10; $k++){
          $html2.='<td style="border: 1px solid #666;">Caja#'.($j+1).'<br>'.$datos[$j].'</td>';
          $j++;
          if($j==$tama){ //Si el dato no tiene las 10 cajas minimas para el for
            break;
             }
            }
    $html2.='</tr>';
```

Tengo por ejemplo tengo 12 cajas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a la hora de querer mostrarlos me muestra solo las 10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo resolver el error en ese codigo?

Comment: ¿Que vale $tama?

Comment: creo que nos tendrías que mostrar como calculas el número de filas

Comment: @JDev es el tamaño del array, segun el codigo si `$j`es igual al tamaño sale, esto es por si el numero de cajas es menor a 10

Comment: @IDanny el numero de filas lo calculo asi `$rows=ceil($tama/10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorre el array de datos y marca cuando quieres abrir o cerrar una fila. Es un modo de hacerlo con un único bucle. Ejemplo con un array de 10 elementos a mostrar en filas de 5:

```
$datos = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$datos_x_fila = 5;

echo "<table>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0 ) { //primera fila
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    //Rellenamos columnas
    echo '<td style="border: 1px solid #666;">Caja#'.($i+1).'<br>'.$datos[$i].'</td>';

    if (($i+1) % $datos_x_fila == 0 && $i>0) {
        if ($i == count($datos)) { //última fila
            echo "</tr>";
        } else { //quedan más filas
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }

    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Si lo quieres hacer con dos bucles, debes tener en cuenta en que fila estás a la hora de recorrer los datos, ya que la primera fila recorrera en mi caso los 5 primeros datos, la segunda los 5 siguientes, etc.

```
$n_rows = ceil(count($datos)/$datos_x_fila);
echo "<table>";

$counter = 0;
for ($r=0; $r<$n_rows; $r++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i=$counter; $i<($datos_x_fila*($r+1)); $i++) {
        if($counter<count($datos)) {
            echo '<td style="border: 1px solid #666;">Caja#'.($counter+1).'<br>'.$datos[$counter].'</td>';
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo el problema lo veo en que **estás incrementado la variable $j** dentro del bucle k, entonces cuando sales del bucle k, $j ya no tiene el valor que tendría que tener, si no un valor más aproximada a k. Debes usar un contador, pero diferente de los que llevan los bucles, si no no te funcionará, y con éste necesitas un bucle for o while para recorrer el array hasta el final.

Un saludo